# Why is "That is your only friend[, whom]/[that] I have ever met." not grammatical?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality

I have seen in some English book that the following sentences are not grammatical:

- That is your only friend that I have ever met.
- That is your only friend, whom I have ever met.

I cannot see any grammatical rules violated in the above sentences. I wonder why they are not grammatical.

Comment: The idiomatic way of expressing these would be *That is the only **friend of yours** that I have ever met* (or use *whom* instead of *that*). I say this as a native English speaker.  However, I don't see what rules would make these sentences ungrammatical rather than just unidiomatic.

Comment: They look OK, if awkward.  The second one shouldn't have a comma in it, though.

Comment: "some English book" What book!!??

Comment: @JamesK The American Heritage Book of English Usage. Is this a bad book? Should I "put it in the bin"?